# Valid Android package names when performing SDK update at command line

Tags: android

You can find the packages available by:

```
android list sdk
```

And then install the corresponding package by the index, however the documentation states you can also update using the package name.

From examples I've seen you can install  SDK Platform Android 4.4, API 19 by:

```
android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter android-19
```

But say I want to install Google APIs, Android API 19, how do I find the corresponding package name to install this package without using the index method?

Most specifically where can I find a list of all the valid package names?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command below should list all valid package names.

```
android list sdk --extended
```